# PHP function call not working on paid host

Tags: php, function, localhost, host

I have a perfectly working code on Localhost, but on the Host it is not working correctly. It's just a single function... What I checked is:

Databases - everything is the same, only the host is different. I Have

```
create_page_header($row["author"],$row["category"], $row["title"],$row["picture"], $row["content"],$row["id"]);

function create_page_header(string $author_id,string $category,string $title,string $picture,string $content, string $id){...}
```

I checked the number of arguments and their data types using var_dump(), they are the same. However, it is not working on host, while working on Localhost.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Nope, I get no errors at all, I tried in the beginning of the function create_page_header to type echo "TEST"; and it did not appear

Comment: 1- Check error_log file
2- Check version of PHP and apache server on local and host server

Comment: You're using string typehints, those weren't added until fairly recently. The version of PHP on the host is probably older than what you're developing with.

Comment: Checked it, on localhost I am with 7.2.1, while the host is with 5.6.34

Comment: I removed the typehints, this was not the issue, since it is still not working.

Comment: Indeed, the problem was because of the version of PHP. Fixed it. Appreciate the fast answers.